# Finding an element with Linq and lambda expressions: but doesn't work

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Have a look to the following example:

The first solution, using the foreach, works pretty well and easily. But I was trying to write it using Linq and I could not achieve this result. I made some attempts but no one succeeded.

I expect to find just one element.

The problem is not at runtime: I don't know very well the Linq sintax and so I don't know how to get the element called PlacedSelection (the foreach structure clarifies where I'm looking for it). Instead in my attempt I could get the PlacedCategory elements.. but I don't need this..

```
PlacedSelection ActualSelection = null;

foreach (var placedCategory in Model.Coupon.Categories)
{
    foreach (PlacedSelection placedSelection in placedCategory.Value.Selections)
    {
        var pp = placedSelection.EventId;
        if (pp == Model.EventId)
        {
            ActualSelection = placedSelection;
            break;
        }
    }
}
//IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, PlacedCategory>> p = Model.Coupon.Categories(c => c.Value.Selections.Any(s=> s.EventId == Model.EventId));
```

Comment: So what *did* happen? You say you didn't succeed, but you didn't say what went wrong. It would really help if you'd provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, to be honest.

Comment: I will edit the question but the problem is not at runtime. The problem is that I don't know very well the Linq sintax and so I don't know how to get the element called PlacedSelection (the foreach structure clarifies where I'm looking for it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want:

```
PlacedSelection actualSelection = Model.Coupon.Categories
    .SelectMany(cat => cat.Value.Selections)
    .FirstOrDefault(selection => selection.EventId == Model.EventId);
```

`Any` would be used if you were trying to find the *category*, but you're trying to find the *selection*, by the looks of it.

Comment: Thanks! Can you add also an example with Any?

Comment: @Revious: No, because `Any` isn't suitable here. It wouldn't achieve what your `foreach` loop does. If you provide a goal where `Any` *would* be suitable, that would be a different matter - but you should be trying to solve your problem, not trying to use a specific method.